# ExUnit how filter tests with two tags?

Tags: testing, elixir, ex-unit

I'm running some tests using Elixir and ExUnit and I would like to pass a filter on the command line that I can select tests that have one tag but not the other.

Example:

- Test A tags: `@foo`, `@bar`
- Test B tags: `@foo`

I'd like to run just the test B with tag `@foo`, but not the A one with `@foo` and `@bar`, how do I achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

`mix test` task accepts any number of file names, as well as `--include` and `--exclude` configs.

More info about tags and filters might be found in [the documentation](https://hexdocs.pm/ex_unit/ExUnit.Case.html#module-filters).

Comment: I tried `--include` and `--exclude`, but as [this doc](https://hexdocs.pm/ex_unit/1.12/ExUnit.Filters.html#functions) says the tests are first excluded, them included. So if I do `--include=foo` and `--exclude=bar` it will run both A and B tests from my example and that's not the behavior I need.
I also can't use file names as I want do select tests dynamically, so I don't know which tests exists

Comment: If you don’t know file names in advance, I am not sure how would you ever decide where to run `@foo` only, and where to run both. Also, you might want to try `@moduletag`.

Comment: Maybe I have a particular use case, but in my context, the tests (that are integration ones, not unit) are triggered by external agents that should pass tags that they want to run (and tags that they do not want to run).

For example, system `A` does is deployed and triggers the integration test suite passing tags to say which tests are related to its context.

Other languages frameworks allow me to do `AND` and `OR` operations when selecting tests with tags.

Comment: Tried `@moduletag`, same result. Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: It looks like "exclude" option is overridden both by "include" and "only" option, so best idea I have is you write your tags to be test suite specific, rather than relying on a combination of tags.